# Microsoft graph how to add Office 365 Voting Buttons to an e-mail Message

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I used to be able to add Outlook Voting Buttons to an e-mail sent by Microsoft Exchange Web Services (EWS). But since moving to Microsoft.Graph have been unsuccessful implementing the functionality to send and receive Microsoft.Graph.Message with Outlook 365 Vote Button functionality.

Does anyone have any idea how to implement such functionality?

Comment: I've successfully added voting buttons using the Graph API from Java. Would you like me to add my code as an answer? It is usually easy enough to convert Java to C# and vice versa.

Comment: Hi Tim,

Adding your Java code would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a java implementation in this question:
[Send exchange email with voting buttons using MS Exchange Graph API Java SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667907/send-exchange-email-with-voting-buttons-using-ms-exchange-graph-api-java-sdk/68668010#68668010)

I believe it should be fairly straight-forward to convert the code to run C#.